# SWIG override function or modify C++ result object

Tags: swig

I have a SWIG generated function as follows:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_StrVector___getitem____SWIG_0(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::vector< std::string > *arg1 = (std::vector< std::string > *) 0 ;
  PySliceObject *arg2 = (PySliceObject *) 0 ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj1 = 0 ;
  std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > *result = 0 ;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"OO:StrVector___getitem__",&obj0,&obj1)) SWIG_fail;
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_std__string_std__allocatorT_std__string_t_t, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "StrVector___getitem__" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "std::vector< std::string > *""'"); 
  }
  arg1 = reinterpret_cast< std::vector< std::string > * >(argp1);
  {
    if (!PySlice_Check(obj1)) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(SWIG_TypeError), "in method '" "StrVector___getitem__" "', argument " "2"" of type '" "PySliceObject *""'");
    }
    arg2 = (PySliceObject *) obj1;
  }
  try {
    result = (std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > *)std_vector_Sl_std_string_Sg____getitem____SWIG_0(arg1,arg2);
  }
  catch(std::out_of_range &_e) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_IndexError, (&_e)->what());
  }

  *****1*****
  ***//I want to modify or print variable result here like printf("%s", result->c_str());***

  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_std__string_std__allocatorT_std__string_t_t, 0 |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

I need to print the variable result at position 1(as mentioned in the code). Typemap(argout)  doesn't seem to be f much help here.

Comment: Can you show the original declaration of the function? I assume this is Python you're targeting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the function you want to modify is a `std::vector<std::string>`'s `__getitem__` routine in Python.

The easiest and safest way to modify or intercept the result of the returned value is actually to do it on the Python side, using `%feature("pythonappend")`, e.g.:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "pyabc.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%feature("pythonappend") std::vector<std::string>::__getitem__ %{
  # do something
  print val
%}

%include "test.h"

%template (StringVector) std::vector<std::string>;
```

The reason this is the easiest way of modifying the result is that the next easiest way of modifying the result requires altering the typemap for the return type - in this case `std::string`. To do that you'd end up altering the existing `std::string` typemap, which gets somewhat messy.

Alternatively you may wish to use the [`%exception`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn44) directive to put some C++ code after `$action`, but unless this is for the purposes of validating the returned result it feels quite hackish.

Comment: thanks a lot awoodland, I've found a solution to my problem but it doesn't seem to be optimal. I've explained the solution and my problem  here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968958/implement-support-for-stdvector-without-std-vector-i). please have a look if you find some time. Thanks :-)