# Implement support for std::vector without std_vector.i

Tags: swig, stdvector

Okay, I've already asked 2 questions about my problem and despite the fact that the replies were really helpful, I am not able to find an optimal solution for my problem. Let me explain my main objective/problem now.

Due to some constraints I can't use std_vector.i in my swig interface, but I need to use a C++ object of (vector of vectors of string)`vector<vector<string>>` in Python. I implemented a solution where I am converting whole `vector<vector<string> >` to Python "List of Lists" wherein I am doing the following conversions:
each C++ string to Python String using `PyString_FromString()`
each `vector<string>` to Python Lists l1, l2, l3, l4...
and finally `vector<vector<string> >` to a Python List containing l1, l2, l3, l4.. as elements.

Although, the above solution works fine and I am able to access the string values in Python but this solution doesn't look optimal to me.

I would prefer a class (without using std_vector.i) whose object I can pass as a function argument to be populated with values and after returning from the function I should be able to access the values using `ob[0][0]` etc. In this way I will have to make only one conversion (C++ string to python string) ,for each value accessed, in `__getitem__`. But I don't know how to define a class representing `vector<vector<string> >` in Python without using `%template`.

Comment: it's vector<vector<string> >. I wrote it in the problem but due to some unknown error it's showing vector> instead of vector<vector<string> >.

Comment: I don't understand the question here - you want to wrap a `std::vector` without using the already supplied interface. You also say you've already written code for `vector<vector<string> >` to list of list. Can you explain, with a *minimal* example what you want to wrap and why neither of those would be sensible?

Comment: okay, I am not using the already supplied interface i.e std_vector.i because it's not available in my organization(we are using our own build tools and libraries, and hence we can't use std_vector.i). currently i am doing something like this:

%apply vector<vector<string> > *OUTPUT {vector<vector<string> >* result};
typemap(in, numinputs=0) vector<vector<string> > *OUTPUT(vector<vector<string> > t) {
$1 = t; }
typemap(argout, fragment = "t_output_helper") vector<vector<string> > *OUTPUT {
$result = t_output_helper($result, my_function_to_convert_vectorToList($1));
}

Comment: using above method i can simply make a call to my function which accepts vector<vector<string> > as argument say void myfunc(vector<vector<string> > *result) like this: lst = ob.myfunc() and i'll get a list of lists as output. This doesn't seem optimal because here i am doing many conversions like, string conversion, vector to list conversion etc. this will make my program slow for large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together an example of a minimal wrapper for `std::vector<std::vector<std::string > >` which works without including any extra SWIG files (e.g. std_vector.i and std_string.i).

I also put together a small header file to test my implementation with:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

inline void print_vec(const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
  std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

inline void print_vec_vec(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v) {
  std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),print_vec);
}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > make() {
  static std::vector<std::string> test1;
  static std::vector<std::string> test2;

  static std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > ret;
  test1.push_back("hello");
  test2.push_back("world");
  test2.push_back("another");
  ret.push_back(test1);
  ret.push_back(test2);
  return ret;
}
```

It's the smallest implementation I could think of that usefully exercises the generated interface.

The SWIG interface I wrote provides a skeleton definition of `std::vector` -  just enough to persuade SWIG to actually wrap the thing. We also extend it for the two cases we care about to provide an implementation of `__getitem__`, the minimum requirement for the `obj[x][y]` syntax you want to be able to use.

```
%module Test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

namespace std {
template <typename T>
class vector {
};
}

%extend std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > {
  std::vector<std::string> __getitem__(unsigned i) throw(std::out_of_range) {
    return $self->at(i);
  }
}

%extend std::vector<std::string> {
  const char * __getitem__(unsigned i) throw(std::out_of_range) {
    return $self->at(i).c_str();
  }
}

%template (VecString) std::vector<std::string>;
%template (VecVecString) std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >;

%include "test.hh"
```

There's a trick there with `c_str()` to avoid including std_string.i. This interface allows me to do things like this in Python:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Test
>>> t=Test.make()
>>> print t[0][0]
hello
>>>
```

It currently doesn't raise the correct type of Python exception in [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). You can do that either with `%include "exception.i"` or with [`%exception`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn44) and writing your own `try`/`catch` around `$action`.

You'll probably also want to provide a similar implementation of `__setitem__` to make this useful.

This is probably no faster than std_vector.i, or your home brew typemap that converts to Python list of list directly. In general though I don't think doing it like this is a good idea -- using the existing std_vector.i implementation instead of reinventing the wheel seems far more logical.